# Create a dictionary property list programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to programatically create a dictionary which feeds data to my UITableView but I'm having a hard time with it. I want to create a dictionary that resembles [this property list (image)](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_ixq8Dp4ESMo/Sc-yvL3FIGI/AAAAAAAAAHY/gsNZ9Qn5CWA/s1600-h/ItemFour.jpg) give or take a couple of items.

I've looked at ["Property List Programming Guide: Creating Property Lists Programmatically"](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html) and I came up with a small sample of my own:

```
//keys

NSArray *Childs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"testerbet", nil];
NSArray *Children = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Children", nil];
NSArray *Keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rows", nil];
NSArray *Title = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title", nil];

//strings

NSString *Titles = @"mmm training";

//dictionary 

NSDictionary *item1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:Childs, Titles forKey:Children , Title];
NSDictionary *item2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:Childs, Titles forKey:Children , Title];
NSDictionary *item3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:Childs, Titles forKey:Children , Title];
NSArray *Rows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: item1, item2, item3, nil];
NSDictionary *Root = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:Rows forKey:Keys];

// NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] //initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: Root];
```

I'm trying to use this data of hierachy for my table views.

So I was wondering how can I can create my property list (dictionary) programmatically so that I can fill it with my own arrays.

I'm still new with iPhone development so bear with me.  ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a situation where "teach a man to fish" is a vastly more helpful approach than "give a man a fish". Once you understand the basic principles and the NSDictionary API, it becomes much easier to craft your own custom solution. Here are a few observations and learning points:

- The method [`+dictionaryWithObject:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObject:forKey:) is used to create an NSDictionary with a single key-value pair. It will not accept comma-separated arguments after each colon (:) in the method call, just one. To create a dictionary with multiple key-value pairs, use one of 2 related methods: [`+dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:) which accepts two NSArray objects containing values and keys, or [`+dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:) which alternates (object, key, object, key) with a terminating `nil` argument.
- Simplify the creation code. You don't need a million local variables just to create the thing. Use inline arguments where it makes sense. One way to do this it to build up your dictionary in code as an [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/), then (if necessary) make an immutable copy of it by calling [`-copy`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy) on it. (Remember that a copy method returns a new object that you must release to avoid memory leaks.) That way you don't have to have a variable for every single value so you can do a "one shot" creation of the structure(s) at each level.
- Use [`+arrayWithObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithObject:) for creating an NSArray with a single object.
- (Style suggestions) Never use an uppercase letter to begin the name of a variable, method, or function. (Notice that SO highlights leading-caps variables like class names.) It will certainly help others who read your code from being confused about your intent by your naming scheme.

Just to give you a flavor of what creating the dictionary in the linked image might look like in code... (I'm ignoring your chosen variable names and using both different approaches for completeness.)

```
NSDictionary *item1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Screen J",[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil]
                                                  forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title",@"View",nil]];
NSDictionary *item2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        @"Screen I", @"Title", 
                                        [NSArray arrayWithObject:item1], @"Children", 
                                        nil];
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand the basic objective here.

It seems like at runtime, you are constructing a deep dictionary with many child nodes.  But you are constructing this all with static code... why can you not simply make a plist (like the one you had an image of) and read that into an NSDictionary?  Both NSDictionary and NSArray have methods that let you simply read in a file and get a whole filled out object.  Then it is WAY easier to edit and to understand.  That method is `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`.

If all of the data is truly created at runtime before it is put into the dictionary, then it seems like you would want a very different, recursive, style of code rather than the flat examples given.

Lastly, I personally dislike the `dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` method in NSDictionary for building a dictionary.  If you have to do things that way I greatly prefer the alternate method `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` which does the same thing but keeps the keys with the objects:

```
NSDictionary *item1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"Screen J",
                       @"Title",
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                       @"View"];
```

Comment: I wanted to test if I was able to pull it off so to speak so that i could later try to make it indeed more recursive and dynamic for instance a little like this
<code>for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { NSMutableArray *theChildren = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 1]; [theChildren addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"tester %d", i]]; NSString *aTitle = [NSString  </code>  You can see the "complete" code below.
Indeed my actual objective is of a more dynamic nature.I'm trying to at least get the dictionary to work so I can start making that dynamic.  
Last but not least Thnx for you feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *topLevel = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSMutableDictionary *item1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *item1title = [NSString stringWithString:@"Title 1"];
NSMutableDictionary *item1children = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

//  create children
NSString *item1child1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"item 1, child 1"];

NSMutableDictionary *item1child2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *item1child2title = [NSString stringWithString:@"Title 1-2"];
NSMutableDictionary *item1child2children = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSString *item1child2child1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"item 1, child 2, child 1"];
NSString *item1child2child2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"item 1, child 2, child 2"];

[item1child2 setObject:item1child2title forKey:@"Title"];
[item1child2children setObject:item1child2child1 forKey:@"item 1 child2 child 1"];
[item1child2children setObject:item1child2child2 forKey:@"item 1 child2 child 2"];

[item1child2 setObject:item1child2children forKey:@"children"];

//  add children to dictionary
[item1children setObject:item1child1 forKey:@"item1 child1"];
[item1children setObject:item1child2 forKey:@"item1 child2"];

//  add to item 1 dict
[item1 setObject:item1title forKey:@"Title"];
[item1 setObject:item1children forKey:@"children"];

NSMutableDictionary *item2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *item2title        = [NSString stringWithString:@"Title"];
NSMutableDictionary *item2children  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; 

NSString *item2child1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"item 2, child 1"];
NSString *item2child2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"item 2, child 2"];
NSString *item2child3 = [NSString stringWithString:@"item 2, child 3"];

//  add children to dictionary
[item2children setObject:item2child1 forKey:@"item2 child1"];
[item2children setObject:item2child2 forKey:@"item2 child2"];
[item2children setObject:item2child3 forKey:@"item2 child3"];

//  add to item 2 dict
[item2 setObject:item2title forKey:@"Title"];
[item2 setObject:item2children forKey:@"children"];

[topLevel setObject:item1 forKey:@"Item 1"];
[topLevel setObject:item2 forKey:@"Item 2"];
```

Comment: thanks man! ... I'm going to check it out and try to play with it a little see if I get these dictionary thingies right;) I also noticed you didn't use any arrays ( I saw the children for instance in the picture link and the sample app) , I hope it still works;) even if it doesn't you have my gratitude. 
again thnx..

Answer (score 0):

first of .. super!  thanks .. I really appreciate the explanation and code snippet. 
Since you gave me such a good explanation I hope you don't mind me asking a couple more questions.

First, I did as you suggested  and this is what I came up with :
(I used my original property list instead of the example this time so this is where the drilldown table gets his( or needs to get his ) treestructure).

http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/7523/picture2lsg.png

```
NSDictionary *root = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSDictionary *item1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"VirtuaGym Online"] forKey:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title"]];
NSDictionary *item2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Do the training"] forKey:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title"]];
NSDictionary *item3 = ... 

[root setObject:item1 forKey:@"Item 1"];
[root setObject:item2 forKey:@"Item 2"];
```

Also did some research and tried something else with some other input..

```
NSMutableArray *Rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 1];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  NSMutableArray *theChildren = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 1];
  [theChildren addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"tester %d", i]];
NSString *aTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Item %d", i];
  NSDictionary *anItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: aTitle, @"Title", theChildren, @"Children"];
  [Rows addObject: anItem];
}

NSDictionary *Root = [NSDictionary withObject: Rows andKey: @"Rows"];
```

I decided to just test both of these however it does what I want. It gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

I was also wondering since I saw you using number in your code snippet, couldn't you also use NSString since that's what the plist uses.. could be totally of here of course

```
NSDictionary *item1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Screen J",[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil]
                                                  forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Title",@"View",nil]];
```

and third a question is about my possible approach to my app. 
I have an xml parser which saves certain information in different arrays. 
I want to use this information for my drilldown UITableviews (infoFirstScreen[] infoSecondScreen[] infoThirdScreen[]). 
The information provided has to be connected like the tree I showed you above.
This is the reason I wanted to build the dictionary in code so I can take the info from my arrays and insert it here. 
My question do you think my approach is correct, wrong or is there a faster way?

again really appreciate the explanation ;)

Comment: If you're trying to ask a separate question, it would be better to post a new question so it gets visibility and answers.